# .htaccess - Simple <Directory> instruction not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Scenario**

I'm trying to use a very simple `<Directory>` instruction in my `.htaccess` file and it's resulting in an apache error.

**Question**

How can I specify RewriteRules for different directories without having to use `.htaccess` files inside those sub directories?

**.htaccess**

```
<Directory "/var/www/my/build/folder">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
    RewriteRule .*   my/build/folder/index.html  [L]
</Directory>
```

**Apache Error**

> ## Internal Server Error
>
> **The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> ---
>
> *Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.mediajackagency.com Port 80*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Directory` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) doesn't work on `.htaccess` context, but on *server config* or *virtual host* context. Either you place the configuration on server/vhost configuration or place an `.htaccess` file in that exact directory.